# Can I view what is using a certain brew formula?

Tags: homebrew

I have loads of installed brew formulas. Some of which I suspect that I might actually not need.

I'm wondering if I can somehow find out why a certain formula is installed (like, what depends on it). Is this possible?

Haven't been able to find anything about this in the docs.

I know I can do the reverse of what I want using `brew info <formula>`, which would show me what is required by the given formula:

```bash
❯ brew info node

==> node: stable 20.3.0 (bottled), HEAD
Platform built on V8 to build network applications
https://nodejs.org/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/20.3.0 (2,446 files, 57.3MB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2023-06-13 at 07:41:26
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/node.rb
License: MIT
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔, python@3.11 ✔
Required: brotli ✔, c-ares ✔, icu4c ✔, libnghttp2 ✔, libuv ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
        Install HEAD version
```

But again, in this example, I wanted to e.g. check `brotli` somehow, and see that it is `node` that depend on it.

I found that there's a (deprecated?) `brew uses` command, but it doesn't seem to work:

```bash
❯ brew uses brotli

Error: Calling brew uses is disabled! Use brew uses --eval-all or HOMEBREW_EVAL_ALL instead.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of `brew` do you use? The latest version does not say anything about `uses` being deprecated or disabled. The message is _"Error: Invalid usage: `brew uses` needs `--installed` or `--eval-all` passed or `HOMEBREW_EVAL_ALL` set!"_

Answer (score 0):

As per docs https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage

> --installed: List dependencies for formulae that are currently installed. If formula is specified, list only its dependencies that
> are currently installed.

So the correct command in your case would be

```
brew uses --installed brotli
```

Cheers